# Using rowspan in table with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I want to insert a table with two columns where the first column contains several rows and second column should contain a single row. To achieve this I wrote code like below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data">
  <td><a href="#">{{ x.no }}</a></td>
  <td ng-if="this.rowIndex === 0" rowspan='{{x.length}}'> ok </td>
</tr>
```

Where data is an array of JSON objects containing single property called no. Using this.rowIndex is correct here or Am I making mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the variable `$index` from the `ng-repeat` directive (see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)).
Furthermore, you read the length of the `x` object; I believe you intended to do so with the `data` variable.

You can see the result in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvZeVV).